# O build do gulp esta alterando o local da div

Tags: html, gulp, build

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do gulp build a coluna muda de local

Comment: Isso é muito estranho, presumo que haja html com problemas de sintaxe. Podes mostrar como reproduzir isso? Podes criar um exemplo ou mostrar onde tens esse código?

Comment: Gustavo, já viste que tens `-` em vêz de `=` nas duas classes no código?

Comment: http://dontpad.com/duvidaGulp

Comment: Em que parte desse código ^ é que isso acontece?

Comment: sao duas tableas cada uma dentro de uma coluna md-06 localmente fica correto mas so depois do build que a coluna desce

Answer (score 0):

Tens sintaxe errada no HTML. Dá uma olhada perto da linha 120, lá encontras `<!--</div>-->` que deixa um elemento `div` sem estar fechado dentro de um `td`.

Depois tens um `</div>`  a mais perto da linha 198, e o mesmo na outra `table`, entre a ultima `tr` e `</tbody>`. Isso é sintaxe inválida.